# how to get data from openERP to C#

Tags: c#, odoo, xml-rpc

I am struggling to understand/find tutorials on how to get data from my OpenERP database.
Now I have a connection between C# and OpenERP and am using cookcomputing.xmlrpc, I get my userid back. So the next step is getting information from my database.
Can someone help me out? Show me some sample code with some explanation?